# Sitecore 10.1.0 yotube video playing issue

Tags: youtube, sitecore, sitecore-mvc

I am trying to link a youtube video in site core 10.1.0, I have done the needful, but the video is not playing, it shows an internal error occurred, below is my code

```
    <video autoplay="" muted="" playsinline="" controls="">
      <source src="https://youtu.be/Eutyxz" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

Comment: Do you have an question about using Sitecore?, or an issue with the html/javascript?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can embed youtube video in the video tag. you have to use iframe to embed youtube videos or download and store the video in the media library and use it in the embed tag.